# Yii How to getState() and display the variable

Tags: php, yii

Im currently doing login and result are worked fine. However , I wish to get the firstname and lastname of the user from DB.

As I know getState() able to get the variable data from the DB.

**Following bellow is the code for login:**

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$userpass = $_POST['userpass']; 


$record=Games::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$username));

if($record===null){
    //somethings
}else if($this->checkPassword($record->password,$userpass)){
    //somethings

}else
{
    $this->_id=$record->id;
    $this->_email=$record->email;

    Yii::app()->user->setState('id', $record->id);
    Yii::app()->user->setState('email', $record->email);
    Yii::app()->user->setState('firstname', $record->firstname);
    Yii::app()->user->setState('lastname', $record->lastname);

    //go to somethings
}
```

**In View**

```
<?php 
    $username_first = Yii::app()->user->getState('firstname');
    $username_last  = Yii::app()->user->getState('lastname'); 
?>
    <a href="#" ><?php echo $username_first.' '.$username_last; ?></a>
```

What is the problem of my code in view ? Any better suggestion to **getState()** the data I need ?

**Updated :**

I tried print out in controller ... it worked ... but why view cant ?

```
print_r(Yii::app()->user->getState('firstname'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getState()` is not dedicated to get variable from database. As Yii's official document defines it:

> Returns the value of a variable that is stored in user session.

By setting state you store your variable's value into user session and you can get that value via `getState()`.

As a suggestion, when you use `getState()`, pass a default value into the second parameter like below:

```
$email=Yii::app()->user->getState('email',NULL);
if(!is_null($email)) //do something
```

It is even better to check state before getting it by `hasState()` like below:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->hasState('email')){
     $email=Yii::app()->getState('email',NULL);
}
```

Another note is that, it is better to get stored values in `Controller` and pass them to the view, not getting them in view. Take a look:

**Controller**

```
$email=Yii::app()->user->getState('email'); //it is better to check it via has state, and also passing a default value 
$this->render('view',array(
    'userEmail'=>$email
));
```

**View**

```
<h2><?php echo $email; ?></h2>
```

**UPDATE**

There is a condition that you may need to just get stored value into session (by `setState()`), So you can just do like below in view:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->hasState('firstname')) { echo Yii::app()->user->getState('firstname'); } //All done
```

Comment: sorry I mistake with explain ... yes from session ...and I tried `print_r(Yii::app()->user->getState('firstname'));` in my controller ... it worked... why in view it cant ? Did you have any example to pass the value to view ? Thanks

Comment: render will load to that page right ? If right, how do I pass the values without load to that page ?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by without load that page, while if you are rendering a view, the content of that view will be rendered. If you do not want to render any view, you can skip rendering. But, if you want to get values in all views without passing into your controller, you can simply do that in view by `Yii::app()->hasState()` and `getState()`. `hasState()` makes you sure that you have the value into session

Comment: If i skip render to view so something like this ? `$firstname=Yii::app()->user->getState('firstname');` 
`$this->render(array('firstname'=>$firstname));` ... it still able to pass value to all page ?

Comment: No dear, When you render a view in a controller, it is dedicated to the controller that rendered it. In each page you must use `getState` in view, or in controller and pass it into view. Also, The syntax of rendering you wrote is wrong. `$this->render('VIEW_NAME',array('firstname'=>$firstname));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63996/discussion-between-the-smile-and-ali-masudianpour).